# SignalR and ServiceStack together error loading System.Web.Razor

Tags: rest, razor, signalr, servicestack

I have been using ServiceStack to handle web requests and just added SignalR support. The problem is when app.MapSignalR() is called... it eventually tries to load System.Web.Razor.dll from the bin directory... however this System.Web.Razor.dll is installed by ServiceStack and has a PublicKeyToken of e06fbc6124f57c43.

But it seems to be looking for a PublicKeyToken of 31BF3856AD364E35 which I'm guessing is Microsofts version of System.Web.Razor because I get the error:

{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}

One weird thing is throughout my Web.config I refer to 31BF3856AD364E35 and it works with I don't make the MapSignalR call. (web.config below). Also, the packages.config is at the bottom of this post.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong and/or how I can resolve this issue?

---- Web.config ---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>

    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="ServiceStack.Razor.CSharpRazorBuildProvider, ServiceStack.Razor" />
      </buildProviders></compilation>
    <httpRuntime />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <!-- Required for IIS 7.0 (and above?) -->
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral" />
    <pages pageBaseType="ServiceStack.Razor.ViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Html" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Razor" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.Text" />
        <add namespace="ServiceStack.OrmLite" />
        <add namespace="OhansonsApi" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---- packages.config ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AWSSDK" version="2.3.47.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Client" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Razor" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

---- portion of csproj file (references) ----

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AWSSDK, Version=2.3.47.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9f476d3089b52be3, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\AWSSDK.2.3.47.0\lib\net45\AWSSDK.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.2.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.4.0.42\lib\net40\ServiceStack.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.Client, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Client.4.0.42\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.Common, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Common.4.0.42\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Interfaces.4.0.42\lib\portable-wp80+sl5+net40+win8+monotouch+monoandroid+xamarin.ios10\ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.OrmLite.4.0.42\lib\net45\ServiceStack.OrmLite.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.4.0.42\lib\net45\ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.Razor, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.4.0.42\lib\net45\ServiceStack.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ServiceStack.Text, Version=4.0.42.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Text.4.0.42\lib\net40\ServiceStack.Text.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e06fbc6124f57c43, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.4.0.42\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run ServiceStack Razor Feature together with Microsoft's Razor in the same Web Application. Normally this would be enough to disable ASP.NET from hijacking Razor `.cshtml` Views:

```
<add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
```

But as this is still an issue, you can try force uninstalling **Microsoft.AspNet.Razor** if you're not using it, e.g:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -Force
```

And do a clean build to remove any .dlls from the project.

If it's still an issue you can try [logging Assembly binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527249/85785) to see if that sheds any light on the underlying cause.

Otherwise I've no idea why SignalR depends on Razor where if it's still a conflict you may have to do without one of them, i.e. by uninstalling **ServiceStack.Razor** (or SignalR).

Comment: So, what I want to do is create a web site that 1) supports rest requests... 2) supports cshtml pages... 3) supports real-time updating... 4) supports ormlite for database access. Would super-love an example project for this... but at least if you could give me the recommended architecture... what I am chose to do was ServiceStack for #1 and #4... and SignalR for #3. Thanks!

Comment: Also... what's the point of the ServiceStack version of razor... I actually was never able to get the ServiceStack rest services and cshtml to work without it.

Comment: @BrianRice If you want to real-time updating you can use ServiceStack's [Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events)  see [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) and [React Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat-React) for live examples. ServiceStack.Razor it's completely optional it provides [smart web views](http://razor.servicestack.net/). Unless you register the `RazorFormat` plugin you're not using it and can safely remove the **ServiceStack.Razor** NuGet package.

Comment: @BrianRice "Supports .cshtml pages" is exactly what ServiceStack.Razor does, but it can't be used with MVC Razor since MVC hijacks handling *.cshtml pages. i.e You can only use ServiceStack's or MVC Razor support. To use MVC Razor, you'll want ServiceStack [mounted at a custom /api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework). Docs on [MVC Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) and [accessing SS from MVC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) are useful